# Trying to get property of non-object when using a SESSION variable in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session-variables

So I'm currently coding a system where when they log in, they get a specialized panel for their ranking.

By default they are called User, and the Admins get, well, Admin.

When I am trying to get the verification that they are an Admin.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // i've been trying to find the bugs with this
require_once('db.php'); //using the good ol $conn = new mysqli
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])){
  header("location: login.php");
  exit;
//to detect if they are logged in or not
}

//here is a failed attempt where I tried to "escape" the $_SESSION variable 
//  which still doesn't work
$username = $conn->real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
// I've tried this query with the $_SESSION variable escaped, with it's alias
// etc.
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `rank` = Admin AND 
`username`='".$username."'";

// preparing to execute
$result = $conn->query($query1);

// this is where I detect if there is a row, set it to use Admin things 
// which I will code later, for now just var holders.
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  $rank = 'Admin';
} else {
  $rank = 'User';
}
```

I've looked everywhere about property of non-object, but I only find old 2008 posts, which I've tried to implement, but end up not working.

Using XAMPP (apache) with PHP 7

Comment: Check you database connection. Also instead of `if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username']))` only `if(empty($_SESSION['username']))` would work.

Comment: the database connection works as I can log into the system. fixed session thingy at the top.

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: it was the property of a non object, the recent answer helped with my fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct your SQL

```
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `rank` = Admin AND `username`='".$username."'"
```

to

```
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `rank` = 'Admin' AND `username`='".$username."'"
```

**Note:** single quote between `Admin`

I would suggest, to use below SQL instead, and store the rank value to `SESSION` directly.

```
"SELECT rank FROM `users` WHERE `username`='".$username."'"
```

Comment: says I can accept the answer in 5 minutes, I actually did this earlier and it worked, but I was dumb and didn't display it, thanks!

Comment: @ArmaanChrist Sure, also, think about my other suggestion. ;-)

Comment: true, but not too concerned setting sessions at the moment, may do it later but for what im doing it isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **mysqli** consider using **prepared statements**. By concatenating the variable values into the query string you are prone to **SQL injection!**.

more on prepared statements here: [php.net/prepared-statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

You were also missing some `' '` in your query, although when using prepared statements you don't need to add any apostrophes on input variables, while the apostrophes around constant strings must be included (they are missing in your example `rank='Admin'`).

**Here is the corrected code:**

**Note:** I moved the `session_start()` to the top of the document to ensure it works properly, since it will not work if any output occurs before calling the function.

```
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('db.php'); //using the good ol $conn = new mysqli

if(empty($_SESSION['username']))
{
   header("location: login.php");
   exit();
}

$query1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE rank='Admin' AND username=?");
$query1->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['username']);
$query1->execute();
$query1->store_result();
$result = $query1->num_rows;

if ($result > 0)
{
   $rank = 'Admin';
}
else
{
   $rank = 'User';
}
```

Comment: not too worried about prepared statements atm, I will probably sanitize the input before they submit.

Comment: @ArmaanChrist Well even with prepared statements you still need to filter your data prior to sending it to the database and sanitize the data you receive from the database, just to be sure everything is taken care of. Filtering and prepared statements are not the same. Prepared statements were introduced with `MySQLi` where the `i` stands for improved. The old procedural way (the way you've shown above) of making queries is a thing of the past and should stay there. Prepared statements, if written properly, eliminate the chance of SQL injection.

Comment: @ArmaanChrist Prepared statements are how secure applications are built nowdays. Here is a link to read [prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection).

Comment: @ArmaanChrist The code I have shown above is the correct way to do it using prepared statements.

Comment: will take into consideration :)